# Nginx - root versus alias, for serving single files?

Tags: nginx

After many hours getting `nginx` to serve single files such as `robots.txt` (hint: *clear your browser cache* each time), I wound up with two different ways, one using the [alias](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#alias) directive, and one using the [root](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#root) directive, like so:

```
location /robots.txt { alias /home/www/static/robots.txt; }
location /robots.txt { root /home/www/static/;  }
```

Is there any *functional* difference between the two? Or security issues? Any conflicts with other directives? (Both seemed fine with another /static location). Or any reason to pick one over the other?

Note - I didn't use both *at the same time* :) Rather I tried each, one at a time, and both worked. I'm not asking how they both interact together in the same file, but which one would be better to use.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Well, these two directives are slightly functional different because you do not use exact match in the latter case. So, `/robots.txt1111` will match your second location too.
`location =/robots.txt { root /home/www/static/;  }` is an exact functional equivalent of your first directive.

Comment: Good point, thanks. But you can use an `=` in both cases, correct? Or does it only apply to `root`? Also, see my edit - I didn't mean to use both at once. :)

Comment: @Cyclops yes, you may use `=` in both cases.

Comment: So they would be the same - is there any reason to pick one directive over the other? Is my main question.

Comment: @Cyclops Basically, there is no such reason.

Answer (score 63):

Yes, there is a difference: With "alias" you can .. well alias to another file name, like

```
location /robots.txt { alias /home/www/static/any-filename.txt; }
```

whereas

```
location /robots.txt { root /home/www/static/; }
```

forces you to name your file on the server also robots.txt. I use the first option since I like to name my robots files on my server as tld.domain.subdomain-robots.txt; e.g

```
location /robots.txt { alias /home/www/static/ch.notex.static-robots.txt; }
```

Answer (score 8):

I think it's worth explicitly laying out that nginx is operating on prefixes and not files per se. In the first case,

```
location /robots.txt { alias /home/www/static/robots.txt; }
```

nginx replaces the string *prefix* `/robots.txt` in the URL path with `/home/www/static/robots.txt` and then uses the result as a filesystem path. Represented as pseudocode, this would be something like:

```
if urlPath.startsWith("/robots.txt") {
    fsPath := "/home/www/static/robots.txt" + urlPath.stripPrefix("/robots.txt")
    serveFile(fsPath)
}
```

So `/robots.txt` is served from `/home/www/static/robots.txt` because `/robots.txt` stripped of the `/robots.txt` prefix is the empty string, and appending the empty string to `/home/www/static/robots.txt` leaves it unchanged. But, `/robots.txt1` would be served from `/home/www/static/robots.txt1` and `/robots.txt/foobar` would be served from `/home/www/static/robots.txt/foobar`. Those files may not exist, causing nginx to send a 404 response, and it's likely that `robots.txt` is not a directory anyway, but nginx doesn't know that in advance, and this is all based on string prefixes and not what *appears* to be a file or directory by the absence or presence of a trailing slash.

Whereas, in the second case,

```
location /robots.txt { root /home/www/static/; }
```

nginx inserts the string `/home/www/static/` at the beginning of the URL path and then uses the result as a file system path. In pseudocode, this would be something like:

```
if urlPath.startsWith("/robots.txt") {
    fsPath := "/home/www/static/" + urlPath
    serveFile(fsPath)
}
```

This has the exact same result as the first case, but for a different reason. There's no prefix stripping, but since every URI path has to contain the prefix `/robots.txt`, then the file system paths will always start with `/home/www/static//robots.txt` which [is equivalent to](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11964/what-do-double-slashes-mean-in-unix-path-is-cd-dir-subdir-valid) `/home/www/static/robots.txt`.

Of course, the pseudocode doesn't quite tell the whole story, as e.g. nginx won't blindly use raw URL paths like `/../../../etc/passwd`, the `try_files` directive changes the behavior of `root`/`alias`, and there are constraints on where `alias` can be used.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference, when the alias is for a whole directory.

```
    location ^~ /data/ { alias /home/www/static/data/; }
```

will work, while

```
    location ^~ /data/ { root /home/www/static/data/; }
```

won't do. This would have to be

```
    location ^~ /data/ { root /home/www/static/; }
```

(Easy to confuse)