# Nginx - map single url to file

Tags: nginx

I'm unable to find how I can map a single URL to a single static file. I tried:

```
location /feeds/seznam/ {
    alias /path/to/file/feed.xml;
}
```

but this does not work (in logs I see that it appends index.html to the path).

Comment: This [answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/278351/nginx-root-versus-alias-for-serving-single-files) for new readers

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
location /feeds/seznam/ {
    rewrite ^/feeds/seznam/$ /path/to/file/feed.xml;
}
```

#### References

- [nginx rewrite virtual directory to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12341917/nginx-rewrite-virtual-directory-to-file)

Comment: Working, but /path/to/file.xml must be the URL path, not a filesystem path.

Comment: @Bruce - can you give me an example?

Comment: @slm, you're looking for `alias /your-file-path;` -- https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias